# Discrete Random Variables and Deep Generative Models - Why Gumbel-Softmax is needed?

Tags: deep-learning, autoencoders, variational-bayes, generative-models

I am reading [this](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5352-semi-supervised-learning-with-deep-generative-models.pdf) 2014 NIPS paper on deep generative models and their application to latent discrete random variables, and [this](https://openreview.net/pdf?id=rkE3y85ee) 2017 ICLR paper on Gumbel-Softmax. I essentially don't understand why we needed the Gumbel reparametrization trick, if the earlier paper in 2014 is already using discrete random variables within the variational framework (without using Gumbel reparameterization).  I know why we use the reparameterization trick in the standard variational auto-encoder. But, it seems the 2014 is just solving the same task as the 2017 paper but without the need for reparameterization.

Answer (score 4):

The paper 2014 paper by Kingma et al does *not* deal with modelling of discrete latent variables per say. In this paper, $y$ represents the discrete label information. When we don't have a label, we instead estimate it using $q_{\phi}(y|x)$ (a classifier). However, this is has no probabilistic interpretation, as we cannot sample from it or score a sample.

To make learning tractable in this model, we instead resort to marginalisation as shown below:
$$p(x) = \sum_{y} p(x, y)$$

You can imagine, as $y$ becomes high-dimensional, marginalisation becomes difficult. Now in the paper by Jang et al, $y$ is a true latent *random* variable. Therefore we can both sample $y \sim q_{\phi}(y|x)$ as well as score it. The main contribution of this paper (and [this same one](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.00712)) is a reparametrisation trick of a relaxed one-hot represented categorical distribution $p(p,\tau)$ that converges to a categorical distribution $\text{Cat}(p)$ as $\tau \to 0$ is annealed.

Comment: Does this mean, using the framework of 2014, we can't do fully unsupervised setting, but the 2017 papers allow us to do this in the fully unsupervised setting?

Comment: Also, it seems in equation 7 we sum over all possible values of $y$, but if we had a classifier in hand (trained using the labelled data), why wouldn't we just first predict the value of $y$ using the classifier, and then just make equation 7 similar to equation 6? The only difference is, in one case we had the label $y$, in the other case we used the classifier to predict it first.

Comment: If we only use the unsupervised bound in the 2014 the contribution from $q_{\phi}(y|x)$ stays constant, therefore it has no effect on training. If we had a trained classifier it would still not be a latent variable model, because that classifier is deterministic.

Comment: If we take equation 7 of the 2014 paper, what exactly changes in the math between this work and the 2017 papers (ignore the reparameterization for now)? Instead of taking the sum over all possible values of $y$, we sample from $q(y|x)$? Is that it?

Comment: Yes, we just sample.

Comment: Still there is something weird going on ... They have really done a bad job writing their paper. Algorithm 2, represents $y_i$ as a sample drawn from $q(y|x)$, but then equation 8 is just a summation over all possible values of $y$.  The puzzling part is, if we enumerate all values of $y$, then the parameters of $q(y|x)$ are not actually involved anywhere in our computation, except in the added term in equation 9 where they try to optimize the classifier.

Comment: The $y$ in algorithm is deterministic, so I agree that the sampling notation is confusing. As you state, the parameters of $q(y|x)$ are optimised by being included in the labelled bound as the auxiliary classification loss. This is enough because the objective is given by $\mathcal{J}^{\alpha}$. You cannot just optimise one of the bounds alone.